# Why does IntToDoubleFunction not come with IntToDoubleFunction andThen(DoubleUnaryOperator after)

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

Why does [DoubleUnaryOperator](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleUnaryOperator.html) come with default implementations for composition like

`DoubleUnaryOperator andThen(DoubleUnaryOperator after);`

but [IntToDoubleFunction](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntToDoubleFunction.html) does not (as of b124, assumed to be feature complete). Is there a special reason that IntToDoubleFunction does not have a

`IntToDoubleFunction andThen(DoubleUnaryOperator after);`
?

Comment: Because a function isn't an operator? Because whoever was designing that spec didn't think the convenience compounding was needed for their usecases?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I just stumbled over this issue - namely the fact that many functional interfaces have an `andThen` method, but many of them (namely, primarily the ones dealing with primitive types) do **not** have such a method. In fact, I considered offering a bounty for this question, because the current answer is not convincing: A function **can** have an `andThen` method. In fact, the reference-typed `Function<T, R>` interface **does** have an `andThen` method! But I found one reason that at least seems convincing for me....</sub>

---

There is no "obvious" reason for the lack of `andThen` methods in the primitive-typed `...Function` interfaces. The only really convincing, technical reason seems to be that offering such methods would impose far too many combinations, due to the specialization of the return- and argument types.

Consider the reference-typed `Function<T, R>` interface, where the `andThen` method is implemented like this:

```
default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
}
```

This allows the type inference at the call site to resolve arbitrary combinations of types:

```
Function<String, Double> f = null;

Function<Double, Long>    g0 = null;
Function<Double, Integer> g1 = null;
Function<Double, Double>  g2 = null;
Function<Double, String>  g3 = null;

Function<String, Long>    c0 = f.andThen(g0); // works
Function<String, Integer> c1 = f.andThen(g1); // works
Function<String, Double>  c2 = f.andThen(g2); // works
Function<String, String>  c3 = f.andThen(g3); // works
```

The analogous combinations, for example, for the `ToDoubleFunction`, would be the following:

```
ToDoubleFunction<String> f = null;

DoubleToLongFunction   g0 = null;
DoubleToIntFunction    g1 = null;
DoubleUnaryOperator    g2 = null;
DoubleFunction<String> g3 = null;

ToLongFunction<String>   c0 = f.andThen(g0); 
ToIntFunction<String>    c1 = f.andThen(g1);
ToDoubleFunction<String> c2 = f.andThen(g2);
Function<String, String> c3 = f.andThen(g3);
```

But this could not be covered with a single `andThen` method. Each argument- and return type of these invocations is different. So instead, due to the specialization of these types, this would require four `andThen` methods in the `ToDoubleFunction` class:

```
ToLongFunction<T> andThen(DoubleToLongFunction g) { ... }
ToIntFunction<T> andThen(DoubleToIntFunction g) { ... }
ToDoubleFunction<T> andThen(DoubleUnaryOperator g) { ... }
<V> Function<T, V> andThen(DoubleFunction<? super V> g) { ... }
```

(and a similar number for all the other primitive-type specializations).

Introducing such a large number of methods would cause an inappropriate bloat of the API - particularly when considering that the lambda notation allows to easily emulate these cases:

```
ToLongFunction<String>   c0 = (t) -> g0.applyAsLong(f.applyAsDouble(t));
ToIntFunction<String>    c1 = (t) -> g1.applyAsInt(f.applyAsDouble(t));
ToDoubleFunction<String> c2 = (t) -> g2.applyAsDouble(f.applyAsDouble(t));
Function<String, String> c3 = (t) -> g3.apply(f.applyAsDouble(t));
```

Answer (score 0):

The javadocs seems to make a distinction between a Function (IntToDoubleFunction) and a UnaryOperator (DoubleUnaryOperator):

[Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)

> Represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.

[Unary Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html)

> Represents an operation on a single operand that produces a result of
>   the same type as its operand. This is a specialization of Function for
>   the case where the operand and result are of the same type.

So according to this, only a UnaryOperator is capable of having `andThen()` since the argument and the result is the same type. For a function, it's not always possible to chain via `andThen()` because the argument and result can be different.